# flexbox vertical center with 100% height

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to use flexbox to center vertically and horizontally for background color purposes?

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
}

.item {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: green;
  align-self: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='item'>
    sdafsdfs
  </div>
</div>
```

If I add a `height: 100%` the text moves back to the top.

Comment: Don't add height: 100%? your snippet is working for me.

Comment: The reason it fails when you add `height: 100%` is because it has no parent with a set height and therefore has default height.

Comment: @JessedeBruijne if I add a height to the flex-item, the background-color is now fullscreen but the text also moves back up, which is not what I want. I want the text to vertically center.

Comment: If you want anything centered both vertically and horizontally, then you should add `display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center` to the parent of the element you want centered.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add display: flex for your items. Then only it can align items inside it as per your requirements. Please have a look at the updated code.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;

}

.item {
  display: flex;
  background-color: green;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;

}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='item'>
    sdafsdfs
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this help

Comment: this shouldn't be accepted answer, it assumes 100% page height, not 100% parent height.

Comment: You must provide your answer if you feel this should not be the accepted answer.

Comment: I found my answer afterwards: 
`display:flex;
flex-direction: column; 
justify-content: center;`