# getting a tad lost in trying to vertically align text

Tags: css

Display flex works great as the variable height columns all equal one another. I have not really used CSS for many years. So I do apologise if I have missed something obvious. Any help would be massively appreciated.

```
.row {
    display: flex;  
}
```

[image: display flex works great as the variable height columns all equal one another]

I followed some S-O posts to vertically align text, however, I cannot seem to replicate the shared success of others.

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;    
}
```

Works however not as I intended, the individual divs bgs no longer stretch, to equal heights.
[image]

I read some further posts and css-tricks, stumbled across align-self stretch.

```css
[class*='col-'] {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 28px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  align-self: stretch;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

This unfortunately seems to go back to my first image. 
[image]

I read another post, highlighting the use of flex:1.
The columns jump around, in a manner, I am not accustomed to. 
[image]

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

[class*='col-'] {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 28px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex: 1;
}
```

If i remove the justify-content and align-items. That does not really help me either.

Here is my markup:

```html
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-m-1 col-t-1 col-d-1' style='background-color:blueviolet;'>
    <a href="" id='navigation_link'>&#9776;</a>
  </div>
  <div class='col-m-1 col-t-2 col-d-2' style='background-color: blue;'>
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </div>
  <div class='col-m-4 col-t-5 col-d-9 t-end' style='background-color:blueviolet;'>
    <form>
      <input type='search' placeholder='Search Today' minlength='100'>
      <input type='submit' value='Search'>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is snapshot of my css

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    /* =24px */
  }

  .col-d-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }

  .col-d-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }

  .col-d-3 {
    width: 25%
  }

  .col-d-4 {
    width: 33.33%
  }

  .col-d-5 {
    width: 41.66%
  }

  .col-d-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }

  .col-d-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }

  .col-d-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }

  .col-d-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }

  .col-d-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }

  .col-d-11 {
    width: 91.66%
  }

  .col-d-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }

  [class*='col-'] {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 28px;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
}

[class*='col-']:first-of-type {
  padding-left: 16px;
}

[class*='col-']:last-of-type {
  padding-right: 16px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, I managed to resolve this problem with the help of this [S-O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46931290/flexbox-vertical-center-with-100-height/46931588) post.

You need to add display flex to the child items; then centre. Thus adding the below snippet to my original post remedies my issue.

```
.row [class*='col-'] {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```